# How to access API data using authentication type 'API key' in Python?

Tags: python, api, sparkpost

I need to access Sparkpost data using their API. They do so via Authentication type = 'API key' instead of Basic Auth. I can do Basic Auth in Python using the code below.

```
import requests
import json
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

Response_API = requests.get('https://api.sparkpost.com/api/v1/metrics/sending-domain?from=2023-01-09T08:00&metrics=count_sent', auth = HTTPBasicAuth('key', 'abcd1234xyz_key'))
Data = Response_API.text
print(Data)
```

I know I can't use this piece of code to get the data from API using 'API key' type. can someone please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass it in headers:

```
headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'x-api-key': API_KEY
}

res = requests.get('https://api.sparkpost.com/api/v1/metrics/sending-domain?from=2023-01-09T08:00&metrics=count_sent', headers=headers)
print(res.text)
```

Comment: thanks, by API_KEY - do you mean the actual key? by the way - either of it didn't work. It gives me NameError

Comment: API_KEY is just a variable that holds the key, try just `api_key` instead of `x-api-key`

Comment: hmm I got you. I did all the changes and now I see error - Unauthorized. so it still didn't work

Comment: Looks like the api key isn't valid

Comment: hey - got to know what changes need to be done. You're all right. Instead of ```x-api-key``` I had to write ```Authorization``` and it works now. not your fault - that keyword is app specific, so for Sparkpost I need to write ```Authorization```. thank you again for your help